# Inkscape: How do I create negative space in an existing object?

Tags: inkscape, layers, transparency

This is what I want:

[image: Image of an A made up of evenly spaced bars]

This is how I achieved it:

[image: same image as above, but showing the top layer is actually lines covering an A]

My goal is to have this embroidered, but I don't want the white bars as part of that. I want it to be true negative space so it would just be whatever I put it on. What is the best way to achieve this in Inkscape?

Answer (score 6):

The  `path->difference` operation could help:

1. to use this the yellow `A` needs to be a path rather than a letter. If this is not the case, convert the letter into a path. Same for the stripes. If they are strokes rather than paths, convert them.

[image]

2. select both the yellow letter and a white bar (red in my picture) and choose the `path->difference` menue

[image]

3. the resulting shape:

[image]